# Laravel prevent users from editing/viewing other users' resources

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel app I have multiple user accounts who have resources that are assigned to them. Say, for example, a "payment". To edit or view a payment a user would visit the `/payment/edit/{payment}` route (where `payment` is the payment ID).

Although I have an auth filter to stop un-logged in users from accessing this page there is nothing to stop, for example, user 1 from editing user 2's payment.

Is there a filter I can user that checks which user a payment (or any other resource) belongs to prevent this kind of issue?

[I am using Laravel's model bindings which automatically fetches the model specified by the route rather than me get it in the controller using eloquent.]

Answer (score 6):

No such filter exists by default, however you can easily create one (depending on how your database is set up). Within app/filters.php, you may do something like this:

```
Route::filter('restrictPermission', function($route)
{
    $payment_id = $route->parameter('payment');

    if (!Auth::user()->payments()->find($payment_id)) return Redirect::to('/');
});
```

This compares the currently logged in user's payment_id (in your database) to the {payment} argument passed into the route. Obviously, depending on how your database is set up (for instance if the payment_id is in a separate table) you need to change the conditional.

Then, apply the filter to your route:

```
Route::get('/payment/edit/{payment}', array('before' => 'restrictPermission'));
```

Comment: That looks close to what I'm after. My table structure is that user hasMany payments. So payments would have a user_id. How would this change the filter? I'd like it to be usable across multiple resources if possible, assuming the same relationship.

Comment: I updated my answer. If a user has many payments, you can simply call the payments() method and chain together any other queries you need (in this case, finding a payment by it's primary key). If the key is not found, it will return null, thus redirecting the user to '/'.

Comment: OK, so there's no way to make a generic filter? I need to make a filter for each model?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to place a where statement in every relevant query. Although not very pretty, it works.

```
$payment = Payment::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->find($id);
```

It's also possible to use url filters like seeARMS is suggesting, however I think it's not very elegant. The most logical place to nest such logic is in the model itself. One possibility is to use [model events](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-events), but this gives you only the option to intercept update, insert or delete statements, not selects. This might change in the future. Maybe you could use `boot()` event, but I'm not sure if this is gonna work.

Last but not least you could use [query scopes](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes).

```
class Payment extends Eloquent {

    public function scopeAuthuser($query)
    {
        return $query->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
    }
}
```

and in the queries you attach the scope

```
Payment::authuser()->find($id);
```

You could do this on a base Model and extend from it, so you have that method in all your relevant models.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Laravel Policies:
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authorization#policy-methods

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Post;
use App\User;

class PostPolicy
{
    /**
     * Determine if the given post can be updated by the user.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Post  $post
     * @return bool
     */
    public function update(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        return $user->id === $post->user_id;
    }
}
```

By policies you can control if given record could be edited by logged user or not.

Cheers!