# Laravel validation site belongs to user

Tags: laravel

My `User.php`

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function sites()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Site::class);
    }
}
```

My `Site.php`

```
class Site extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

My `routes.php`

```
Route::resource('site', 'SiteController');
```

My `SiteController.php`

```
class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function edit(int $id)
    {
        $site = Auth::user()->sites()->find($id);

        return view('site.edit', compact('site'));
    }
}
```

How can I validate that the site belongs to user? I understand that in my case if site doesn't belong to user, `$site` variable will be null. But I want more declarative way, something like laravel requests, because I need the same check in `show`, `update`, and `destroy` methods. But I cannot use laravel request, because checking is something like this

```
$siteId = Route::current()->param('site');
$ids = Auth::user()->sites()->pluck('id')->toArray();
$result = in_array($siteId, $ids);
```

Can anyone suggest how to achieve my goal?

Comment: I find solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22618389/laravel-prevent-users-from-editing-viewing-other-users-resources?rq=1. Simply use route filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I use laravel 5.2, solution with route filters is deprecated. Instead route filter we should use middleware.
app/Http/Middleware/RestrictPermission.php

```
class RestrictPermission
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $siteId = Route::current()->parameter('site');

        if (!Auth::user()->sites()->find($siteId)) {
            abort(403);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

app/Http/Kernel.php

```
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'restrict.permission' => RestrictPermission::class,
    ];
}
```

SiteController.php

```
class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('restrict.permission', ['except' => [
            'index', 'create', 'store',
        ]]);
    }

    public function edit(int $id)
    {
        $site = Auth::user()->sites()->find($id);
        return view('site.edit', compact('site'));
    }
}
```